# copy files to Nexus 4 on Kubuntu (13.04)

Tags: usb, mount, android, mtp, nexus-4

I know, this has been asked a few times already but I'm still having troubles to get files copied my new Nexus 4 phone mounted on my Kubuntu 13.04 machine. I followed the guide at: http://www.pocketables.com/2013/03/how-to-mount-the-lg-nexus-4-as-a-usb-drive-in-linux.html
I would only get:

```
 $ cp -r /mnt/media/Albums/A\ Perfect\ Circle\ -\ Thirteenth\ Step/ .
cp: accessing ‘.’: Transport endpoint is not connected
reg@regDesktopHome:/media/nexus4/Internal storage/Music$ ls -l
```

but thereafter , `mount` still shows it mounted:
`mtpfs on /media/nexus4 type fuse.mtpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other)`

What's going on here?
Thanks for the assistance!

***edit***

When I tried to fsck it,I got this:

```
$ sudo fsck /media/nexus4
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
fsck.ext2: Is a directory while trying to open /media/nexus4

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a correct ext2
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>

$
```

and copying a direcory with `cp -r` would actually only copy the directory but no contents and then afterwards I would try to do a copy of the contents, it would look like:

```
reg@regDesktopHome:/media/nexus4/Internal storage/Music/A Perfect Circle - Thirteenth Step$ cp /mnt/media/Albums/A\ Perfect\ Circle\ -\ Thirteenth\ Step/* .
reg@regDesktopHome:/media/nexus4/Internal storage/Music/A Perfect Circle - Thirteenth Step$ ls -l
total 0
reg@regDesktopHome:/media/nexus4/Internal storage/Music/A Perfect Circle - Thirteenth Step$
```

What's up with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have hit a quirk in the fuse mount point. You should try to unmount, run fsck or reboot the system.

```
sudo fsck /media/nexus4
sudo umount /media/nexus4
```

If it still doesn't unmount, then reboot the system. Once you have unmount the filesystem, mount the device again.

Comment: when I try tio fsck it, see above what I got - also, on the shell it seemed like I could copy something, it toojk a while to complete  and no errors but after it had seeminly completed the copy, a directory was present but no files within it :(

Comment: Oh and I have mounted and umounted the system multiple times in between so that should not be the problem... it seems to fall back into the `endpoint not connected` state whenever I try to use Dolphin instead of the shell, thus for now, shell only...

Comment: Err... in that case, that sounds like a bug.